# Bash tilde *substring* expansion - undocumented feature?

Tags: bash

I was surprised that this expansion:

```
$ echo "${foo:~abc}"
```

yielded the empty string when `foo` was unset. I expected that it would parse like this:

```
$ echo "${foo:(~abc)}"
```

and yield the string "~abc". But instead, I found that if I *did* define

```
$ foo='abcdefg'
$ echo "${foo:~abc}"
g
```

In fact, it's taking "abc" in arithmetic context and doing. `"${foo:~0}"`. Likewise

```
$ foo='abcdefg'
$ echo "${foo:~3}"
defg
```

It gets you the last n+1 characters of the expansion. I looked in the "Parameter Expansion" section of the manpage. I see no mention of tildes there. [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification) only mentions tildes as (also undocumented) case modifiers.

This behavior goes back to at least 3.2.57.

Am I just missing where this form of substring expansion is documented, or is it not documented at all?

Comment: Since the `:~` doesn't exist I guess it gets parsed as the `${parameter:offset:length}` Substring expansion since it's the closest in syntax, although `offset` gets a weird value. And that's why you are getting a substring. The documentation is in the [Bash Reference Manual, under "Shell Parameter Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not undocumented (you may have been confusing `${foo:~abc}` with `${foo-~abc}`).

```
${parameter:offset}
${parameter:offset:length}
     Substring Expansion.  Expands to up to length characters of  the
     value  of  parameter starting at the character specified by off-
     set.  [...]  If length is omitted, expands to the  substring  of  the
     value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset
     and extending to the end of the value.  length  and  offset  are
     arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION below).
```

Here, `~abc` is the offset field of the expansion, and `~` is the bitwise negation operator in the arithmetic expression. An undefined parameter evaluates to 0 in an arithmetic expression, and `~0 == -1`.

Comment: Nicely figured out. I had just realized that it seemed to be "inverting" the number in some way but hadn't figured out how yet.

Comment: ah, I ascribed too much mysticism to how this was being parsed. Thanks!